# Roslyn C#: How to get all fields and properties (and their belonging class) accessed by a method

Tags: c#, abstract-syntax-tree, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I wish to calculate the *Access To Foreign Data* metric for my methods. Furthermore, I would like to know from which objects my methods are accessing fields and properties to determine the existence of *feature envy* code smells.

For this example:

```
public class DoctorService
{
    private List<Doctor> _doctors;
    public Doctor FindAvailableDoctor(DateRange timeSpan)
    {
        foreach (Doctor d in _doctors)
        {
            foreach(DateRange holiday in d.HolidayDates)
            {
                d.Test = null;
                if (!holiday.OverlapsWith(timeSpan)) return d;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and specifically the FindAvailableDoctor method, I would like to build a list of accessed fields that would contain the HolidayDates and Test property of the Doctor class. I would also like to know both these properties belong to the Doctor class (identified by the class name and its namespace).

I've made the following code to acomplish this:

```
var accessedFields = member.DescendantNodes().OfType<MemberAccessExpressionSyntax>();
foreach (var field in accessedFields)
{
    var symbol = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(field.Expression).Symbol;
    switch(symbol)
    {
        case ILocalSymbol local:
            fields.Add(new CaDETMember { Name = local.Type + "|" + local.Name });
            break;
        case IPropertySymbol prop:
            fields.Add(new CaDETMember { Name = prop.ContainingSymbol + "|" + field.ToString() });             
            break;
        case IParameterSymbol param:
            fields.Add(new CaDETMember { Name = param.Type + "|" + field.ToString() });
            break;
    };
}
```

and have started fiddling about with the fields of the Symbol API. However, this solution is both unclean and I am pretty sure will miss some edge cases for non-trivial code.

What would be a better way to extract the field and property names accessed by a method, so that I can also know which class the accessed fields and properties belong to?

Edit: Based on Jason's answer, I went with the following solution:

```
var accessedFields = semanticModel.GetOperation(member).Descendants().OfType<IMemberReferenceOperation>();
foreach (var field in accessedFields)
{
    fields.Add(new CaDETMember {Name = field.Member.ToDisplayString()});
}
return fields;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is actually a perfectly fine approach, so don't feel too bad about it. There's a second way to do it which is to use the IOperation APIs. If you call SemanticModel.GetOperation() that gives you a tree of IOperations you can walk through which represent the semantic operations being performed at various points in the code. In particular there's an [IMemberReferenceOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.operations.imemberreferenceoperation) that will point to the member being referenced. So something like:

```
var memberReferences = semanticModel.GetOperation(methodSyntax).Descendants().OfType<IMemberReferenceOperation>()
```

will let you look at those and then get the symbols from there. There's other operations for local accesses too.

Comment: one thing I noticed with this solution is that it does not catch access performed when returning a field. For example, a property that has the code "get { return _a;}" will not register the _a as a IMemberReferenceOperation. Any idea how to expand your code elegantly to include this case?